# Changing the link text in a child node (parent node has ID) without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I understand how to change the link text of a node that has an ID, like this:

```
<div>
    <a id="Link1" href="foo">ABCD</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("Link1").firstChild.textContent = "WXYZ";
</script>
```

But how do you tackle the same problem when the node doesn't have an ID, but the parent div does? Or in other words, why doesn't this work?

```
<div id="Link2">
    <a href="foo">ABCD</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("Link2").firstChild.firstChild.textContent = "WXYZ";
</script>
```

Thanks for any help!!!

PS - I can make this work in jquery using text(), but I can't use any external libraries for the specific project I'm working on, so it needs to be native javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
document.getElementById("Link2").firstElementChild.innerHTML = "WXYZ"; //Or
//document.getElementById("Link2").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML = "WXYZ";
```

Because `firstChild` in your case will be a text node inside the `div` added by formatting. So you can use [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.firstElementChild) to get the element and use `innerHTML` which is of more crossbrowser support when compared to textcontent.

Comment: @mikedaul: You should be aware that `firstElementChild` doesn't work in IE8 or lower.,

Comment: @cookiemoster - that's good to know. So would using the children[] method be more backwards compatible?

Comment: @mikedaul: Yes. If I recall, Firefox 3 didn't support `.children`, but that shouldn't be an issue at this point.

Comment: @cookiemonster children is not supported in IE8 below as well.

Comment: @PSL - a follow up question... the page I want to edit has multiple instances of the same ID and unfortunately I am unable to change the code. Running the script only replaces the first instance. What's the best way to iterate over and replace the others?

Comment: @cookiemonster Do you have specs? I am not sure... I think it is not.

Comment: @mikedaul Never do that. Do not duplicate ids. Your ids selector will select only the first one with the match. Instead give them all same class name and use `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: You need to read the [1] footnote: *Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8 supported it, but erroneously includes Comment nodes*. That table should include it as supported, but with a caveat.

Comment: @PSL: `getElementsByClassName` isn't supported in IE8 and below either.

Comment: Because there will be many millions of people using it for many years to come. There's a significant barrier to upgrading to IE9. Anyone using Windows XP can't upgrade, and those users will be around for a long time.

Comment: Why are you telling me to take it easy? I'm just answering your question.

Comment: @PSL - I know it breaks validation, but it's not my code and it's beyond my control. I have access to editing the head of the document, but not the body where the content gets rendered - hence needing to replace linked text in the first place... thanks at any rate!!

Comment: @mikedaul Which older browsers you need to support?

Comment: @PSL - IE 8+ is what we aim for, but I'm fine with degraded experience for older browsers - core functionality will still be there. I'm just trying to make an old product more user-friendly...

Comment: @PSL - I've got a funky hack sort of working for iterating, so no further help needed. 

Thank you all for such quick responses. SO is amazing :)

Comment: @mikedaul You could use attribute selector, but will be slow. http://jsfiddle.net/r2rgQ/

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('Link2')
    .getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerText = 'WXYZ';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements in many ways with native JavaScript, here's a couple ways to do this:

```
document.querySelector("#Link2 a").innerText = "Foobar";
document.getElementById("Link2").firstChild.innerText = "Foobar";
document.getElementById("Link2").childNodes[0].innerText = "Foobar";
```

Or (from the first answer):

```
document.getElementById('Link2').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerText = "Foobar";
```